# Trying to align an image in html using align="middle". Image is being aligned to left

Tags: html, alignment

I am trying to Align an image in html to middle

```
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f5x3MaZ6fqQ/maxresdefault.jpg " align="middle" , width="740" height="382" />
```

however the image keeps being pulled to the left of the screen. I tried nesting it in a div, as suggested by a friend but, it didn't work.
Is this some obvious noob error I am making?

Here is the link to the Code Pen Page

http://codepen.io/jaygo/pen/JXZRJQ?editors=1100

Also sorry in advance if my question is badly structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To horizontally align an image, or any other form of inline content, set `text-align: center` on the parent element using CSS.

The `align` attribute is deprecated and should not be used any more. `middle` is a description of vertical, not horizontal, alignment. Comma characters are not allowed between attributes in HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify. I would need to create a new class  '.text-align' in my css and then target the parent element using jquery?

Comment: @Goharij — No. `text-align` is the property name. You'd write a new CSS rule-set with a selector that matched the parent element of the image and put that rule in there. You wouldn't involve JavaScript at all (unless you wanted to modify it dynamically, but in that case you would probably still be better off putting everything in the stylesheet and then using JS to modify the elements belonging to the classes).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the commas from your markup, it is not valid HTML.
Align is a deprecated property going forward, so this should be done using CSS.

If you are using a style sheet (recommended!) you can use the following:

```
img{ display: block; margin: 0 auto; } 
//this will apply to all images in your site. I would use a class instead
```

Or if you are not using a stylesheet you can do it inline

```
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f5x3MaZ6fqQ/maxresdefault.jpg " width="740" height="382" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

Edit: Apologies Quentin is right, you need to set the image to 'display: block' as well. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Here is also a working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/pcfa8oLL/

Comment: Thank you very much. That really clarifies it.

Comment: That won't work. Auto margins have no effect on elements which are `display: inline` (and images are by default).

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer if it helped with your problem.